# Need a way to record JDBC requests

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and, I'm trying to perform load testing. I got many ideas about HTTP request recording.

But now I have to perform Load Testing on a MS SQL database. But I am not getting any recording tool or any way to extract all SQL queries that are performed in background for the JDBC request. I tried "SQL Server Profiler" but I did not get much from there. Is there any other ways or tools to extract queries for application?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Profiler should be able to record the queries, however if you are experiencing problems with it you can try alternative options like:

- Using [ExpressProfiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) tool
- Use [SQL Server Trace Flag 4032](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-trace-flag-4032/) (don't forget to turn it off once you're done)

In general you shouldn't be testing the database directly unless you have already figured out that the database is the bottleneck and trying to figure out the most optimal configuration. In that case I believe [Using JDBC Sampler In JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter) article will shed some light on the [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) options